# Swiper not working until I resize browser window

Tags: javascript

I using wrap-swiper-slide for present my video and track. i have 2 dynamic content. First video content is hide. But swiper incorrect working util i resize browser windown. has anyone had this problem. Please help me

Comment: We'll need your code to fix your problem.

Comment: A good example here: https://codepen.io/1wdtv/pen/jbjZeb

Comment: Nathaniel Flick properties of content show in the first page load is correct. but it incorrect working if it hide in the first page load.